# SIPp: Cancel scenario 487 before 200

Tags: sip

I'm trying to simulate how to deal when 487 comes before 200 in cancel scenario. But i get "Aborting call on unexpected message for Call-Id while sending (index 5), received 'ACK sip:service@192.168.1.20:5060 SIP/2.0" error.
this is my server.

```
<scenario name="Basic UAS responder">

<recv request="INVITE" crlf="true">
</recv>
<send>
<![CDATA[

    SIP/2.0 100 Trying
    [last_Via:]
    [last_From:]
    [last_To:]
    [last_Call-ID:]
    [last_CSeq:]
    Contact: <sip:[local_ip]:[local_port];transport=[transport]>
    Content-Length: [len]

]]>
</send>
<send>
<![CDATA[

    SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
    [last_Via:]
    [last_From:]
    [last_To:];tag=[call_number]
    [last_Call-ID:]
    [last_CSeq:]
    Contact: <sip:[local_ip]:[local_port];transport=[transport]>
    Content-Length: [len]

]]>
</send>

<recv request="CANCEL">
</recv>
<send>
<![CDATA[

    SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated
    [last_Via:]
    [last_From:]
    [last_To:]
    [last_Call-ID:]
    CSeq: [cseq] INVITE
    Contact: <sip:[local_ip]:[local_port];transport=[transport]>
    Content-Length: [len]

]]>
</send>

<send>
<![CDATA[

    SIP/2.0 200 OK
    [last_Via:]
    [last_From:]
    [last_To:]
    [last_Call-ID:]
    [last_CSeq:]
    Contact: <sip:[local_ip]:[local_port];transport=[transport]>
    Content-Length: [len]

]]>
</send>





<!--pause milliseconds="4000"/-->
<recv request="ACK"
crlf="true">
</recv>


</scenario>
```

this is my client

```
<scenario name="UAC Cancel">

<send retrans="500">

<![CDATA[

    INVITE sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
    To: <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>
    From: <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]; tag=[call_number]
    Call-ID: [call_id]
    CSeq: [cseq] INVITE
    Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
    Max-Forwards: 70
    Content-Length: [len]

]]>
</send>

<recv response="100" optional="true">
</recv>

<recv response="180">
</recv>

<pause milliseconds="4000"/>

<send>
<![CDATA[

    CANCEL sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
    [last_Via:]
    To: sip:[service]@[local_ip]:[local_port]>[peer_tag_param]
    From: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port];tag=[call_number]
    Call-ID: [call_id]
    [last_CSeq:]
    Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
    Max-Forwards: 70
    Content-length: [len]

]]>
</send>

<recv response="200" optional="true">
</recv>

<recv response="487" next="cancelACK">
</recv>

<label id="cancelACK"/>
<send>
<![CDATA[
    ACK sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port] SIP/2.0
    [last_Via:]
    To: <sip:[service]@[remote_ip]:[remote_port]>[peer_tag_param]
    From: <sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port];tag=[call_number]
    Call-ID: [call_id]
    CSeq: [cseq] ACK
    Contact: sip:sipp@[local_ip]:[local_port]
    Max-Forwards: 70
    Content-Length: [len]
]]>
</send>
<pause milliseconds="3000"/>

</scenario>
```

Comment: You are using `[SIPp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: yes I am using SIPp.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you'll have a problem with the way your are using [last_Via:].

The CANCEL request from the UAC should have a new branch parameter in its Via header since it's a new transaction.

Also the OK response to the INVITE request being generated by the UAS is going to use the Via header from the CANCEL request.

Since the Via header is critical for SIP transaction matching it's understandable that sipp is complaining when it is not able to match things up properly.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but I had the same problem with SIPp when trying to CANCEL an INVITE.
The issue was sorted out by sharing the same *branch=xxxx* in *Via* header on INVITE and CANCEL. This is to group the CANCEL request in the same transaction as the INVITE.

[This is the Github link where I took the solution from](https://github.com/davidcsi/sip-tester/blob/b10e6606c5d887ee8c598022df152aa7fcd05c37/app/sip-tester/scenarios/cancel.xml#L66).

Anyway, as *sipsorcery* pointed out, SIPp wanted to start a new transaction setting a new branch in the CANCEL, but that was failing in my scenario.

The piece of to extract the *branch* and use it later:

```
<recv response="100" optional="true">
    <action>
       <!-- Extract the value of branch in Via header and store it in branch variable -->
       <ereg regexp=";branch=[^;]*" search_in="hdr" header="Via" check_it="false" assign_to="branch"/>
    </action>
</recv>
<recv response="180" optional="true"/>
<recv response="183" optional="false"/>
<send>
<![CDATA[
CANCEL sip:[field3]@[field4] SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port][$branch] <-- Use the branch variable
From: "LibonQA VTP1" <sip:[field0]@[field2]>;tag=[call_number]
...
```